# Kingfisher image resize on image loaded from url

Tags: ios, swift3

I HAVE uitableview, and in this uitableview I got a cell. This cell has a 2 uiimageview next to each other with equald widths.I want both this 2imageviews to take the entire width, 1st imageview half the width screen second imageview the other half. I am getting the images from kingfisher, how can i  the image got from url be resized based on width. If my image container is 200x200 for example, which is half the original image dimensions 400x400. I want my image height to resize from 400. If I got 300x 400, I want width to be 150 and  height to resize to 200, maintaining the aspect ratio, then resize the cell in process.

How can this be done using kingfisher?

Answer (score 6):

Using Kingfisher i did the following.

```
let url = URL(string: urlImage)

    cell.imageView?.kf.setImage(with: url,
                                placeholder: nil,
                                options: [.transition(ImageTransition.fade(1))],
                                progressBlock: { receivedSize, totalSize in
                                    print("\(indexPath.row + 1): \(receivedSize)/\(totalSize)")
    },
                                completionHandler: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in

                                    print("\(indexPath.row + 1): Finished")
                                    print(image?.size)
                                    cell.imageView?.image = self.resizeImage(image: image!, newWidth: 40.0)

    })
```

You cand modify the resizeImage function in order to change your image size, in my case i made a square image.

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    let scale = newWidth / image.size.width
    let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```

or you can user KingfisherManager

```
KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: url!, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in

        cell.imageView?.image = ImageUtils.resizeImage(image: image!, newWidth: 40.0)

    })
```